# Install two different versions of Office on Windows7

Tags: microsoft-office

I have installed Office 2007 and Office 2013 on my Windows 7 laptop. Both of them are installed under C: Program Files (x86). However, whenever I tried to open Office 2013, it always opens Office 2007. Even when I tried to use commend line and  it still opens Office 2007.

```
C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office 15\root\office15\winword.exe
```

Does anyone have an idea how to solve the problem? Thanks!

Comment: Is there a specific reason you have them both installed?

Comment: I had Office 2013 already installed on my machine and Office 2007 was installed by one of my friend who doesn't know computer at all. He said he want to use Office 2007 because his teacher told him to install Office 2007 for school work. And now I can't use Office 2013 at all.

Comment: I have Office 2010 and Office 2013 installed on the same PC.  Besides some add-ons hating it and being disabled because they both are installed there shouldn't be a problem.  The installation directories are different.  `Office 15` is Office 2013 by the way.

Comment: There is no need to install 2007. Word 2013 is (mostly) backwards compatible with it: https://support.office.com/en-za/article/Open-a-Word-2013-document-in-an-earlier-version-of-Word-45c4dd2f-bf7b-4a0d-9ff2-7b2ff6b733f0

Comment: @krowe - Its fully compatible with it except for add-ons that specifically only work with Office 2007.

Comment: @Ramhound The link I gave was fairly comprehensive and did mention that as well. If you use add-ons then you'll need to deal with those as is appropriate. A chart, for example, could be easily fixed by converting it to an image and embedding that instead. UI enhancements can be ignored. Other add-ons may require more effort. At the end of the day, add-ons should just be avoided for homework assignments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you still need Office 2007? If so, in your control panel, go to Add/Remove Programs, click on Office 2013, and then click "Repair". It will most likely give you the option of an offline or online repair. Try offline first, then try online if it doesn't work.

If you don't need Office 2007 anymore, first uninstall it in Add/Remove Programs, then run a repair on Office 2013 like I said above.

If Office 2007 wasn't uninstalled too long ago, you may be able to do a system restore to before it was installed.

Comment: I actually just did system restore. Unfortunately it was just after office 2007 was installed. And when I deleted office2007. Every time I tried to open office 2013 it will stop working. And I can't uninstall office 2013 because the uninstall program stops working as well.

Comment: @Edyyy Try the repair, it should fix your issue.

Comment: @Edyyy Like krowe said, repair should help. Unfortunately, in my experience, the Office 2013 installer can definitely run into major issues. One of the best helps I've found is to install "From CD" instead of using the online installer. If you sign into your Office account to install Office, you can click Install Using CD > Download CD. You can then mount the downloaded .iso using many different tools. I've used Daemon Tools Lite before.

Comment: @dotbat I did as you said above. However the repair also stopped working when I opened it. One thing I'm concerned right now is how to uninstall both of them? I could uninstall Office 2007 without problems. But after that the Office 2013 uninstall would stop working. Do I need to uninstall all the files by hand?

Comment: @Edyyy You may have to do it manually. [This](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2739501) Microsoft KB tells you how, although the site seems to be broken, so [here](http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache%3Asupport.microsoft.com%2Fkb%2F2739501&oq=cache%3Asupport.microsoft.com%2Fkb%2F2739501&aqs=chrome..69i57j69i58.2471j0j4&sourceid=chrome&es_sm=93&ie=UTF-8) is the Google cached version. I have literally had to wipe computers before because of issues with Office 2103 installations, so I wish you luck!

Comment: @dotbat That's a little bit work to do but it helps. Thanks!